# Eclipse command for Play 2.4 application with sub projects

Tags: eclipse, playframework-2.4, subproject

I have a Play 2.4.2 project with two sub-projects. I have my `build.sbt` declared like this -

```
lazy val abc = (project in file("modules/abc")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

lazy val def = (project in file("modules/def")).enablePlugins(PlayScala, PlayJava)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean).dependsOn(def, abc)
        .aggregate(def, abc)
```

But when I try to execute `eclipse` command, two eclipse projects are created for two sub-projects, no project for my main application.

Can anyone suggest how I can fix it for eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Include following line to your `build.sbt`:

```
EclipseKeys.skipParents in ThisBuild := false
```

Or generate your eclipse projects with a `skip-parents` flag set to false:

```
eclipse skip-parents=false
```

More details [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/IDE#Generate-configuration).